# Ref object is possibly undefined TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that uses a hook to set the input value into component state. I want to add a class when the input value is more than 0 characters in length, however I'm coming across an issue where TypeScript says my ref may be undefined.

I can't get rid of this error even if I check if the ref exists in the conditional that wraps the code to add the class. I'm not sure on the solution to this.

**Error:** `Object is possibly 'undefined'` on       `inputValue.current.classList.add(inputHasContentClassName);`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Component: React.FC = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const inputHasContentClassName = 'input--has-value';

    if (inputValue.length > 0 && inputValue) {
      inputValue.current.classList.add(inputHasContentClassName);
    } else {
      inputValue.current.classList.remove(inputHasContentClassName);
    }
  }, [inputValue]);

  function handleInputChange(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setInputValue(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('Submit form');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <input
              ref={myRef}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              type="number"
            />
            <label>Input Label</label>
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            disabled={inputValue.length === 0}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

Comment: just add an if like , if (myRef !== null) then do rest actions

Comment: Is this code edited after the accepted answer has been given? It seems the inputValue has been a ref maybe, but now is just a string.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`useRef()` returns an object with a `current` property, which contains the object you actually care about. And before the first render is complete, that `current` property will be null. This means the type of that ref is:

```
{ current: WhateverTypeYouCareAbout | null }
```

And that means you have to handle `null` as a possible value of the `current` property. But the ref object itself will always exist, it's just that its `current` property may be `null`.

I would simply store the `current` value of your ref in a variable, test that existence, and then use it.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const inputHasContentClassName = 'input--has-value';
    const inputElement = inputValue.current;        

    if (inputElement && inputElement.value.length > 0) {
      inputElement.classList.add(inputHasContentClassName);
    } else {
      inputElement.classList.remove(inputHasContentClassName);
    }
  }, [inputValue]);
```

You can also tell the TypeScript compiler the type of your ref (in this case `HTMLInputElement`) by doing the following:

```
const myRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
```

Comment: This resolves the initial error but I then get "classList" does not exist on type "never" even if I check for inputElement: `inputElement && inputElement.classList.add('classname')`

Comment: Managed to solve it with `const inputElement = (myRef.current as unknown) as HTMLInputElement;` but this feels like a hack.

Comment: Try `useRef<HTMLInputElement>();`

Comment: @AlexWayne - Thank you :-)

```useRef<HTMLInputElement>(); ```

Comment: Don't use ref as a hook dependency. This is not reliable, as mutating the ref won't trigger a re-render: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476155/is-it-safe-to-use-ref-current-as-useeffects-dependency-when-ref-points-to-a-dom

Answer (score 1):

Following this blog https://medium.com/@dimterion/modals-with-html-dialog-element-in-javascript-and-react-fb23c885d62e with my Dialog component. I got the ref.current my be possibly undefined and adding the type helped clear the error.

```
const DeleteDialogue = ({ showModal, hideModal, firstName, deleteUser }) => {
  //if (!showModal) return null
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>()

  useMemo(() => {
    if (showModal) {
      ref.current?.showModal()
    } else {
      ref.current?.close()
    }
  }, [showModal])
  return (
    <dialog
      className="modal modal-sheet position-static d-block bg-secondary py-5"
      role="dialog"
      tabIndex={-1}
      id="modalSheet"
      ref={ref}
      onCancel={hideModal}
    >
```