# Is it safe to use ref.current as useEffect's dependency when ref points to a DOM element?

Tags: reactjs

I'm aware that ref is a mutable container so it should not be listed in `useEffect`'s dependencies, however `ref.current` could be a changing value.

When a ref is used to store a DOM element like `<div ref={ref}>`, and when I develop a custom hook that relies on that element, to suppose `ref.current` can change over time if a component returns conditionally like:

```
const Foo = ({inline}) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  return inline ? <span ref={ref} /> : <div ref={ref} />;
};
```

Is it safe that my custom effect receiving a `ref` object and use `ref.current` as a dependency?

```js
const useFoo = ref => {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const element = ref.current;
      // Maybe observe the resize of element
    },
    [ref.current]
  );
};
```

I've read [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14387#issuecomment-503616820) saying ref should be used in `useEffect`, but I can't figure out any case where `ref.current` is changed but an effect will not trigger.

As that issue suggested, I should use a callback ref, but a ref as argument is very friendly to integrate multiple hooks:

```js
const ref = useRef(null);
useFoo(ref);
useBar(ref);
```

While callback refs are harder to use since users are enforced to compose them:

```
const fooRef = useFoo();
const barRef = useBar();
const ref = element => {
  fooRef(element);
  barRef(element);
};

<div ref={ref} />
```

This is why I'm asking whether it is safe to use `ref.current` in `useEffect`.

Answer (score 157):

It isn't safe because mutating the reference **won't trigger a render**, therefore, **won't trigger** the `useEffect`.

> React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'ref.current'.
> Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like
> 'ref.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't
> re-render the component. **(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)**

An anti-pattern example:

```
const Foo = () => {
  const [, render] = useReducer(p => !p, false);
  const ref = useRef(0);

  const onClickRender = () => {
    ref.current += 1;
    render();
  };

  const onClickNoRender = () => {
    ref.current += 1;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ref changed');
  }, [ref.current]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClickRender}>Render</button>
      <button onClick={onClickNoRender}>No Render</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit xenodochial-snowflake-hhgr6]

---

A **real life use case** related to this pattern is when we want to have a persistent reference, **even when the element unmounts**.

Check the next example where we can't persist with element sizing when it unmounts. We will try to use `useRef` with `useEffect` combo as above, **but it won't work**.

```
// BAD EXAMPLE, SEE SOLUTION BELOW
const Component = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  const [isMounted, toggle] = useReducer((p) => !p, true);
  const [elementRect, setElementRect] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current);
    setElementRect(ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect());
  }, [ref.current]);

  return (
    <>
      {isMounted && <div ref={ref}>Example</div>}
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(elementRect, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Bad-Example, Ref does not handle unmount]

---

Surprisingly, to fix it we need to handle the `node` directly while memoizing the function with `useCallback`:

```
// GOOD EXAMPLE
const Component = () => {
  const [isMounted, toggle] = useReducer((p) => !p, true);
  const [elementRect, setElementRect] = useState();

  const handleRect = useCallback((node) => {
    setElementRect(node?.getBoundingClientRect());
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isMounted && <div ref={handleRect}>Example</div>}
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(elementRect, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Good example, handle the node directly]

- See another example in React Docs: [How can I measure a DOM node?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node)
- Further reading and more examples see [uses of `useEffect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947)

Comment: In case a ref is passed to a DOM element, I think every DOM change is caused by a render, and an effect should trigger after a render is committed beginning with comparing `ref.current`, is it possible to still miss some ref updates when it is only used to reference a DOM?

Comment: Do you have an example of such case? (it wont trigger render)

Comment: I can't have an example where DOM change won't trigger a render so I'm wondering why it is unsafe to use DOM ref.current in useEffect

Comment: @otakustay If you relaying on DOM change why you using a dep array? Put the logic in useEffect without a dep array. ref.current as dependency is useless as mentioned in the answer

Comment: Because ref can be changed form div to span, or from null to div across multiple renders, but empty deps array can run effect only once on the first mounted DOM element.

Comment: Is this still the case if the ref is a prop? Because it seems to work fine for us as long as the `ref.current` comes from a parent component rather than `useRef()`.

Comment: @Slbox thats like a normal pattern of forwarding ref, its ok.

Comment: @DennisVash, any thoughts on how to handle the situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75621592/how-can-i-properly-determine-when-a-conditionally-rendered-child-components-for?

Comment: the code examples need to be typed, it's extremely difficult to implement any of this without them

Answer (score 75):

**2021 answer:**

This article explains the issue with using refs along with `useEffect`: [Ref objects inside useEffect Hooks](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780):

> The useRef hook can be a trap for your custom hook, if you combine it with a useEffect that skips rendering. Your first instinct will be to add ref.current to the second argument of useEffect, so it will update once the ref changes.
> But the ref isn’t updated till after your component has rendered — meaning, any useEffect that skips rendering, won’t see any changes to the ref before the next render pass.

Also as mentioned in this article, the official react docs have now been updated with the recommended approach (which is to use a callback instead of a ref + effect). See [How can I measure a DOM node?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node):

```
function MeasureExample() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
      <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Damn, React feels like writing Java in the old days. So much verbosity for simple things.

Comment: yes it scares me thinking of the fact that functional component is already a huge cut from class component

Comment: Come back JQuery all is forgiven!

Comment: And then you still need ResizeObserver.  From the official docs:

`In this example, the callback ref will be called only when the component mounts and unmounts, since the rendered <h1> component stays present throughout any rerenders. If you want to be notified any time a component resizes, you may want to use ResizeObserver or a third-party Hook built on it.`

Comment: what are the types?

Comment: I change my mind about React, this is all getting ridiculous. For one, they could have significantly lowered the learning curve by passing the "render context" as a parameter into a component (render) function, instead of calling "hooks" and making them look like magic.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem and I created a custom hook with Typescript and an official approach with ref callback. Hope that it will be helpful.

```
export const useRefHeightMeasure = <T extends HTMLElement>() => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)

  const refCallback = useCallback((node: T) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height)
    }
  }, [])

  return { height, refCallback }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem wherein my ESLint complained about `ref.current` usage inside a `useCallback`. I added a custom hook to my project to circumvent this eslint warning. It toggles a variable to force re-computation of the `useCallback` whenever ref object changes.

````
import { RefObject, useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";

/**
 * This hook can be used when using ref inside useCallbacks
 * 
 * Usage
 * ```ts
 * const [toggle, refCallback, myRef] = useRefWithCallback<HTMLSpanElement>();
 * const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    if (myRef.current) {
      myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [toggle]);
  return (<span ref={refCallback} />);
  ```
 * @returns 
 */
function useRefWithCallback<T extends HTMLSpanElement | HTMLDivElement | HTMLParagraphElement>(): [
  boolean,
  (node: any) => void,
  RefObject<T>
] {
  const ref = useRef<T | null>(null);
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const refCallback = useCallback(node => {
    ref.current = node;
    setToggle(val => !val);
  }, []);

  return [toggle, refCallback, ref];
}

export default useRefWithCallback;
````

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue while trying to use `ResizeObserver`.  Ended up using callback reference `observeRef` that I pass back from the custom hook which does the observing.

```
import { useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';

export interface ElementDimensions {
  contentWidth: number;
  contentHeight: number;
  clientWidth: number;
  clientHeight: number;
  scrollWidth: number;
  scrollHeight: number;
  isOverflowingX: boolean;
  isOverflowingY: boolean;
  isOverflowing: boolean;
}

export interface UseResizeObserverResponse {
  observeRef: (target: HTMLElement) => void;
  dimensions: ElementDimensions;
}

/**
 * @returns ref to pass to the target element, ElementDimensions
 */
export const useResizeObserver = (): UseResizeObserverResponse => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState<ElementDimensions>({} as ElementDimensions);
  const observer = useRef<ResizeObserver | null>(null); // we only need one observer instance
  const element = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);

  const handleResize = useCallback((entries: ResizeObserverEntry[]) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(entries)) {
      return;
    }

    const entry = entries[0];
    const newDimensions: ElementDimensions = {
      contentWidth: entry.contentRect.width,
      contentHeight: entry.contentRect.height,
      clientWidth: entry.target.clientWidth,
      clientHeight: entry.target.clientHeight,
      scrollWidth: entry.target.scrollWidth,
      scrollHeight: entry.target.scrollHeight,
      isOverflowingX: entry.target.clientWidth < entry.target.scrollWidth,
      isOverflowingY: entry.target.clientHeight < entry.target.scrollHeight,
      // compute once on access then replace the getter with result
      get isOverflowing() {
        delete this.isOverflowing;
        return (this.isOverflowing = this.isOverflowingX || this.isOverflowingY);
      },
    };

    setDimensions(newDimensions);
  }, []);

  // initialize resize observer
  const observeRef = useCallback(
    (target: HTMLElement) => {
      // the callback ref fires often without a target, so only process when we have a target
      if (!target) {
        return;
      }

      // instantiate a new observer if needed
      if (!observer.current) {
        observer.current = new ResizeObserver((entries) => handleResize(entries));
      }

      // monitor the new element with cleanup of the old element
      if (element.current !== target) {
        element.current && observer.current?.disconnect(); // call disconnect if monitoring old element
        observer.current.observe(target);
        element.current = target;
      }
    },
    [handleResize]
  );

  return { observeRef, dimensions };
};
```

Use it

```
  const { observeRef, dimensions } = useResizeObserver();
  console.log('Observed dimensions: ', dimensions);
  return <div ref={observeRef} >Observe me</div>;
```

Tests

```
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useResizeObserver } from './useResizeObserver';

describe('useResizeObserver', () => {
  let listener: ResizeObserverCallback;
  let mockObserverInstance: ResizeObserver;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockObserverInstance = {
      observe: jest.fn(),
      unobserve: jest.fn(),
      disconnect: jest.fn(),
    };

    window.ResizeObserver = class MockResizeObserver {
      public constructor(ls: ResizeObserverCallback) {
        listener = ls;
      }
      public observe(elem: HTMLElement) {
        mockObserverInstance.observe(elem);
      }
      public disconnect() {
        mockObserverInstance.disconnect();
      }
    } as typeof ResizeObserver;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    listener = undefined as unknown as ResizeObserverCallback;
    mockObserverInstance = undefined as unknown as ResizeObserver;
    window.ResizeObserver = undefined as unknown as typeof ResizeObserver;
  });

  it('should return a callback ref', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useResizeObserver());
    expect(result.current).toEqual({ observeRef: expect.any(Function), dimensions: {} });
    expect(mockObserverInstance.observe).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should synchronously set up ResizeObserver listener', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useResizeObserver());
    expect(listener).toBeUndefined();

    act(() => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      result.current.observeRef(div);
    });

    expect(typeof listener).toBe('function');
  });

  it('should monitor element target with observer', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useResizeObserver());
    expect(result.current).toEqual({ observeRef: expect.any(Function), dimensions: {} });
    expect(mockObserverInstance.observe).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    const elem: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');
    result.current.observeRef(elem);
    expect(mockObserverInstance.observe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(elem);
  });

  it('should stop monitoring old element when new element is provided', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useResizeObserver());
    expect(result.current).toEqual({ observeRef: expect.any(Function), dimensions: {} });
    expect(mockObserverInstance.observe).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    const elem: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');
    result.current.observeRef(elem);
    expect(mockObserverInstance.observe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(elem);
    expect(mockObserverInstance.disconnect).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    const elem2: HTMLElement = document.createElement('span');
    result.current.observeRef(elem2);
    expect(mockObserverInstance.disconnect).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockObserverInstance.observe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(elem2);
  });

  it('should not update dimensions when no entries provided to listener', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useResizeObserver());

    let div: HTMLElement;
    act(() => {
      div = document.createElement('div');
      result.current.observeRef(div);
    });

    act(() => {
      listener(undefined as unknown as ResizeObserverEntry[], {} as ResizeObserver);
    });

    expect(result.current.dimensions).toMatchObject({});
  });

  it('should track rectangle of a DOM element', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useResizeObserver());

    let div: HTMLElement;
    act(() => {
      div = document.createElement('div');
      result.current.observeRef(div);
    });

    act(() => {
      listener(
        [
          {
            target: div,
            contentRect: {
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
            },
          } as unknown as ResizeObserverEntry,
        ],
        {} as ResizeObserver
      );
    });

    const expectedDimensions = {
      clientHeight: 0,
      clientWidth: 0,
      contentHeight: 200,
      contentWidth: 200,
      isOverflowing: false,
      isOverflowingX: false,
      isOverflowingY: false,
      scrollHeight: 0,
      scrollWidth: 0,
    };

    expect(result.current.dimensions).toMatchObject(expectedDimensions);
  });

  it('should compute overflow of target DOM element', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useResizeObserver());

    let div: HTMLElement;
    act(() => {
      div = document.createElement('div');
      result.current.observeRef(div);
    });

    act(() => {
      listener(
        [
          {
            target: {
              clientHeight: 100,
              clientWidth: 100,
              scrollWidth: 200,
              scrollHeight: 100,
            },
            contentRect: {
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            },
          } as unknown as ResizeObserverEntry,
        ],
        {} as ResizeObserver
      );
    });

    const expectedDimensions = {
      clientHeight: 100,
      clientWidth: 100,
      contentHeight: 100,
      contentWidth: 100,
      isOverflowing: true,
      isOverflowingX: true,
      isOverflowingY: false,
      scrollHeight: 100,
      scrollWidth: 200,
    };

    expect(result.current.dimensions).toMatchObject(expectedDimensions);

    act(() => {
      listener(
        [
          {
            target: {
              clientHeight: 100,
              clientWidth: 100,
              scrollWidth: 100,
              scrollHeight: 200,
            },
            contentRect: {
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            },
          } as unknown as ResizeObserverEntry,
        ],
        {} as ResizeObserver
      );
    });

    const expectedDimensions2 = {
      clientHeight: 100,
      clientWidth: 100,
      contentHeight: 100,
      contentWidth: 100,
      isOverflowing: true,
      isOverflowingX: false,
      isOverflowingY: true,
      scrollHeight: 200,
      scrollWidth: 100,
    };

    expect(result.current.dimensions).toMatchObject(expectedDimensions2);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I've stopped using `useRef` and now just use `useState` once or twice:

```
const [myChart, setMyChart] = useState(null)

const [el, setEl] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
    if (!el) {
        return
    }
    // attach to element
    const myChart = echarts.init(el)
    setMyChart(myChart)
    return () => {
        myChart.dispose()
        setMyChart(null)
    }
}, [el])

useEffect(() => {
    if (!myChart) {
        return
    }
    // do things with attached object
    myChart.setOption(... data ...)
}, [myChart, data])

return <div key='chart' ref={setEl} style={{ width: '100%', height: 1024 }} />
```

Useful for charting, auth and other non-react libraries, because it keeps an element ref and the initialized object around and **can dispose of it directly as needed**.

I'm now not sure why `useRef` exists in the first place...?

Comment: Based on Dan's comment here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14387#issuecomment-503616820
`Refs are for values whose changes don't need to trigger a re-render.`
And I agree with that statement there are instances that you don't need a re-render and just need to keep a reference of something in your code e.g. component, a counter, etc.

Comment: Strange, so is `ref` in a `return <div ref={ref}>` not intended to be used with `useRef`? Because I *do* want to trigger execution of a block once that `div` element is assigned and that triggering is usually done with `useEffect`, like in the question.

Comment: Ref changes don't trigger a re-render. Chances are some of your components triggered a re-render and just about time that your ref also changed and was captured by your `useEffect`.

Comment: But we **do** want to capture the cases once the DOM element is assigned. That's why `useRef` isn't that useful in the majority of cases and why I think it shouldn't ever connect to an element's `ref={ref}`. Per the docs it seems like the recommended way is to rather use a "callback ref" (see answer by Gyum Fox). I'm thinking a `useState` can also work and is simpler.