# How to extend a ref type for forwardRef in react and typescript to allow multiple refs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

#### This code validates under typescript:

```js
type Ref = HTMLTableElement;

const Table = forwardRef<Ref, shapeTable>(({filtered, handleSort, paginationOptions, summary, onMount}, refTable) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if(refTable && typeof refTable !== 'function' && refTable.current) {
      const tableWidth:string = window.getComputedStyle(refTable.current).getPropertyValue("width");
      onMount(tableWidth);
    }
  }, [refTable, onMount]);
```

#### This code does not validate under typescript:

When I put the type refTable inside an object as below, and I update the Ref type to allow for that, it does not validate. How can I fix this? I need to be able to pass more than one ref into forwardRef. I have done this previously without using typescript and it works. So something about forwardRef seems to insist only one ref type can pass. Unless its a simpler matter of updating my Ref type:

**Type '((instance: Ref | null) => void) | MutableRefObject | null' is not assignable to type 'Ref'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Ref'.**

```js
type Ref = {
  refTable: HTMLTableElement
};

const Table = forwardRef<Ref, shapeTable>(({filtered, handleSort, paginationOptions, summary, onMount}, ref) => {
  const {refTable}:Ref = ref;

  useEffect(() => {
    if(refTable && typeof refTable !== 'function' && refTable.current) {
      const tableWidth:string = window.getComputedStyle(refTable.current).getPropertyValue("width");
      onMount(tableWidth);
    }
  }, [refTable, onMount]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about which properties are on which objects.  In the second example you have a ref to an object with a `refTable` property.  If your ref is a ref object (not a callback ref) then it would look like:

```
ref = {
  current: {
    refTable: HTMLTableElement,
  }
}
```

So you need to look for `current` on the ref **first** and **then** look for `refTable` on `ref.current`.

Revised code:

```
const Table = forwardRef<Ref, shapeTable>(({ filtered, handleSort, paginationOptions, summary, onMount }, ref) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref && typeof ref !== 'function' && ref.current) {
      const table = ref.current.refTable;
      const tableWidth = window.getComputedStyle(table).getPropertyValue("width");
      onMount(tableWidth);
    }
  }, [ref, onMount]);
  
...
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0pXN)

Be aware that using refs in `useEffect` dependencies is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476525/10431574).

Comment: Hi thanks for the response to this. Its been a while and my typescript has improved. So busy right now but will try to get a chance to check this. Thankyou