# How to pass an object to a generic function in typescript

Tags: typescript

#### this code validates under typescript

```
interface MutableRefObject<T> {
  current: T;
}

const $div = document.querySelector('div');

type shape = HTMLDivElement | null;

const obj: MutableRefObject<shape> = {
  current: $div
};

console.log('obj = ', obj);
```

#### This code fails:

*** Type '{ refDiv: { current: HTMLDivElement | null; }; }' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'refDiv' does not exist in type 'MutableRefObject' ***

```js
interface MutableRefObject<T> {
  current: T;
}

const $div = document.querySelector('div');

type shape = {
  refDiv: HTMLDivElement | null
};

const obj: MutableRefObject<shape> = {
  refDiv: {
    current: $div
  }
};

console.log('obj = ', obj);
```

Is it because I need to define a particular literal type within my type? If so how?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're making a subtle mistake here, your `current` object has a property named `refDiv` not the way around.

```
interface MutableRefObject<T> {
  current: T;
}

const $div = document.querySelector('div');

type shape = {
  refDiv: HTMLDivElement | null
}


const obj: MutableRefObject<shape> = {
  current: {
    refDiv: $div,
  }
};

console.log('obj = ', obj);
```

Comment: Ahhh. Yes that could be it. Thankyou. I'm trying to understand why I can't pass an object of html elements to react method forwardRef ref, instead of just one ref. I dont think I can change their defined MutableRefObject as they have declared similar to above. I have another question I asked prior to this. Your solution works here but not in context. Are yoi able to look for me? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373915/how-to-extend-a-ref-type-for-forwardref-in-react-and-typescript-to-allow-multipl

Comment: I'll look at it ASAP. in the mean time, I suggest that you close this question. @SteveTomlin

Comment: Sorry for delay