# Using useRef addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using `useRef` for `addEventListener` but doesn't work, is something wrong here?

**parent component:**

```js
const parent = () => {
  const el = useRef()
  const element = el.current && el.current 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (element) {
      const scrollHandler = e => {
        console.log(e);
      };

      element.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);

      return () => {
        element.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
      };
    }
  }, [element]);

  return (
    <Child ref={el} />
  )
}
```

**child component:**

```js
const child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>something...</div>
  )
})
```

Comment: For `scroll` event to work, content of the `Child` component needs to have enough height for the webpage to be scrollable. Try setting `200vh` height on the `div` element in `Child` component. Then you will see the `scroll` event working as it should.

Comment: Useref doesn't trigger rerender, and bound ref object before useEffect. Just use el.current without element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6094348/yousaf Yeah you are right, i have enough scroll for element, but still doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6165701/cenk-%c3%87etinkaya I did it as you said, but still doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6094348/yousaf Thank you so much for helping me, but i want `element.addEventListener` not `window.addEventListener` i wrote wrong dude. may you check again?

Comment: Here's [the working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-wind-s4hyf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). For `scroll` event to work on an element, that element should be scrollable and you need to use `el.current` instead of `element` inside the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6094348/yousaf Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `React Hook Flow` the `useEffect` will be called after the child is being rendered and the `refs` are set, so you should be able to empty the `useEffect` dependency and still having a `ref` that's being set.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Check this comment from Dan as well which might be helpful for clarification of what's happening: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14387#issuecomment-503616820

also created this codesandbox that you can play with code to see what I'm talking about: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-cache-jgv7xw
change your parent component to this to avoid getting `stale state`:

```
const parent = () => {
  const el = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (el.current) {
      const scrollHandler = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
      };

      el.current.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);

      return () => {
        el.current.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return <Child ref={el} />;
};


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxEQ4.jpg
```

Comment: @Yousaf I didn't say `Stale Props` . `element constant is unneccessary here and it may result in `Stale State`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11432102/taghi-khavari Thanks dude, can you see my question again i did some edit

Comment: you're welcome. I changed My answer . you don't need `element variable` use your `el variable` directly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11432102/taghi-khavari Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Do not do this! The `useEffect` will not update when the ref gets updated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476155/is-it-safe-to-use-ref-current-as-useeffects-dependency-when-ref-points-to-a-dom

Comment: Thanks @aarowman for pointing that out, you're right it was an old answer and I updated it 