# useEffect not triggered upon changes in the object it "listens" to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

I am learning React and currently having difficulties understanding how useEffect really supposed to work. What I am trying to accomplish is to make useEffect execute when the object it 'listens' to changes, but it doesn't happen.

I.e. according to the following tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/using-useeffect-in-react-js-functional-component :

*We can pass a second argument to useEffect, if there is any change on the second argument then React will execute this useEffect function call.*

So here's my code, in which counter is the second argument/the object useEffect "listens" to:

```
function CounterUseRef() {

  const counter = useRef(0);

  function handleClick() {
    counter.current = counter.current + 1;
    console.log(counter.current);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect"); 
  }, 
  [counter.current]
  //[counter]
  
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter {counter.current}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default CounterUseRef;
```

When the button is clicked, `handleClick()` gets executed and `counter.current` gets incremented, so I thought this would constitute "any change on the second argument".
However, `setEffect` doesn't get executed. It doesn't get executed even if I make `counter.current` itself the second argument.

Would really appreciate any help.

P.S. I do realize for a use case like this, `useState` should have been used instead. What I really trying to figure out why `useEffect` is not working.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to put a ref in a useEffect dependency array. Isn't the point of a ref is that it doesn't affect renders? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476155/is-it-safe-to-use-ref-current-as-useeffects-dependency-when-ref-points-to-a-dom

Comment: @evolutionxbox I wouldn't agree with that 100%, as sometimes you want to run an effect once the ref exists, so you'll put it in the dependency array and wrap the logic inside the effect in a `if (ref.current)`.  But in *this* case, a ref is not the way to go.  `counter` is better off as a state variable

Comment: I see the question has been closed, but the short answer to your question is: the function doesn't run again because your component never rerenders - as you can also observe from the fact that the counter value in the <h1> always displays 0. Changing a ref doesn't cause a rerender, only updating props or state does that. And effects can only run after a render.

Comment: @SethLutske but in that scenario I don't think it's the ref that causes the useEffect to run?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'm not sure who marked this as a dupe.... I only linked the question because I thought it was related. Maybe it could do with being reopened?

Comment: I wasn't criticising the marking as a duplicate - most likely this has been asked before, and I never checked the link. I was simply trying to give the OP a simple explanation of what they were (or rather weren't) seeing in their component.

Comment: (@RobinZigmond I didn't think you did )

Comment: @evolutionxbox "I don't think it's the ref that causes the useEffect to run" you are making me rethink my life

Comment: Thank you, guys, for clarifying things for me. Really appreciate your help