# Refactor triggering useEffect on extraneous dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I have a component:

```
function Component({ children }) {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something based on ref.current size
  }, [])

  return <div ref={ref}>{children}</div>;
}
```

I would like to do something based on the change of the size of the div. The size will change when the children changes. However, with the currect code, useEffect will only fire once and won't react to `children` change.

I can't put `ref` in the dependencies array as this won't retrigger useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // no effect
}, [ref]);
```

I could put `children` in the array but this smells wrong - it's definitely an antipattern.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // works but blah
}, [children]);
```

What would be the idiomatic react way to handle this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68175873/detect-element-reference-height-change this helps?

Comment: yeah it basically suggests using ResizeObserver as the answer here. Perhaps it's a duplicate then