# useEffect is not called when dependencies change

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-ref

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [minus, setMinus] = useState(3);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setMinus(minus - 1);
  };

  console.log(
    "--> ref and state",
    ref.current?.innerHTML ?? ref.current,
    minus
  );

  // first useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`denp[ref.current] >`, ref.current?.innerHTML ?? ref.current);
  }, [ref.current]);

  // second useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`denp[minus]>`, ref.current?.innerHTML ?? ref.current);
  }, [minus]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {(minus >= 0 || minus <= -5) && <h1 ref={ref}>num: {minus}</h1>}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>minus</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

On the first render: the first useEffect is run and log out: denp[ref.current] > num: 3

I press the button, the state minus is updated to 2, the component is re-rendered

On the second render: the first useEffect is run and log out: denp[ref.current] > num: 2

I press the button, the state minus is updated to 1, the component is re-rendered

On the third render: the first useEffect is not run anymore

Why the first useEffect does not run on the third render?

Live code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mayer-3f8zsl

Comment: ref.current doesn't seems to be a reliable dependency, as React is raising this warning:
React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'ref.current'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 'ref.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Comment: Yes I read the warnings and the doc but I do not know exactly what happened? Can you explain what each re-render does, please?

Comment: I sadly does't have the knowledge to explain what is happening here, sorry

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to use ref as a dependency, so use **ref.current.innerHTML** instead of **ref.current**.
I teseted It with **ref.current.innerHTML** and it worked for me
hope helping you

Comment: Yes it worked, maybe it is related to the ref.current which is a DOM node. The DOM Node is the same but different value in the second and third render

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should not rely on the ref as a dependency, since it is not triggering updates, as it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476155/is-it-safe-to-use-ref-current-as-useeffects-dependency-when-ref-points-to-a-dom).

Comment: Yes, but I really want to know what exactly happened? I did this but in the third render, I expect the useEffect is called
- first render
    - state: 3
    - ref: null
    - render DOM → update ref = 3
    - run useEffect → log ref 3
- second render
    - state: 2
    - ref: 3
    - compare old ref (null) vs new ref (3)
    - render DOM → update ref = 2
    - run useEffect → log ref 2
- third render
    - state
    - ref 0
    - compare old ref (3) vs new ref (0)
    - render DOM → update ref = null
    - run useEffect → log ref null

Comment: Yes, I agree that is is weird

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Next.JS (maybe applies to any SSR), I would suggest also setting the dependency to ref.current?.innerHTML and then it will work.