# Related useEffects where the first one updates a dependency of the second are causing weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, async-await, react-hooks

### **Edited code block to include console logs from accepted answer.**

I have a search bar component that I have *completely* stripped down to its simplest possible form:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const resultTypes = ["categories", "submissions", "users"];

const SearchBar = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [selectedResultType, setSelectedResultType] = useState(resultTypes[0]);

  console.log("render --------");

  console.log("selectedResultType: " + selectedResultType);

  const selectedResultTypeRef = useRef(null);
  console.log(
    "selectedResultTypeRef.current: " + selectedResultTypeRef.current
  );

  const fetchResults = async () => {
    console.log("fetching...");
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3"
    );
    setResults(response.data);
    console.log("setResults: ", response.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect 1 ---------");
    selectedResultTypeRef.current = selectedResultType;
    console.log(
      "selectedResultTypeRef.current: " + selectedResultTypeRef.current
    );
  }, [selectedResultType]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect 2 ---------");
    // No need to debounce fetch when changing result type
    fetchResults();
  }, [selectedResultTypeRef.current]);

  return (
    <div className="SearchBar__container">
      <div className="SearchBarResults__types">
        {resultTypes.map((resultType) => (
          <button
            key={resultType}
            onClick={() => {
              console.log("click " + resultType + " -------");
              setSelectedResultType(resultType);
            }}
          >
            {resultType}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

When I click between my 3 buttons (categories, submissions, and users), I expect the `selectedResultType` to change, which will then change `selectedResultTypeRef.current` so I can pass it into a memoized, debounced function. I removed all of this because it's not relevant, but that's the reason I need to use refs instead of just component state.

Here's my problem: When I call the async function and wait for a response to set results, it seems that `selectedResultTypeRef.current` only changes (or is recognized as a change) every other click. I've tried different combinations of clicking through the 3 buttons, and it's always every other click that triggers the hook that calls `fetchResults`.

Here's the console output using the above code:
[image]

Oddly, it fetches twice after missing a fetch for the previous ref change. I really don't know why this is. What's also curious is that when I replace the `setResults` line with just a simple `console.log(response.data)`, it never misses a hook. Here's the console output from that:
[image]

My suspicion is that the `setResults` update somehow triggers a re-render of the dom (even though I'm not using the `results` state anywhere in this simplified version), and it interferes with `selectedResultTypeRef` being recognized as an update that gets captured by the `useEffect` hook. I don't know why it's every other update, but I've at least verified its consistent pattern.

Other than that, I'm completely at a loss. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: "I removed all of this because it's not relevant, but that's the reason I need to use refs instead of just component state." has all the hallmarks of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). React refs can be mutated at any time, so they are, or should be, an obviously inherently terrible React hook dependency because they are not coupled to the React component lifecycle at all. Try to take a step back and re-asses and explain what you are really trying to accomplish. This may very well mean including ***all*** the relevant code you are working with in a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I'm answering to the question "Why is this happening?" and not to the "How to build a search bar with debouncing?" because the details was intentionally omitted.

It is important to remember that:

- Calling the setter from `useState` causes a rerender if the data has changed. Despite the fact that the data is not used.
- The effect checks its dependency list during the render, when `useEffect` is called.
- Those effects whose dependencies has changed are executed **after** the render phase.

Now let's say everything is loaded. `selectedResultType === "categories"` and `selectedResultTypeRef.current === "categories"`.

1. Click on `submissions` button. `setSelectedResultType` is called and rerender started.
2. Checking the dependencies: `selectedResultType` has changed to `submissions` so `effect 1` will be called after the render. `selectedResultTypeRef.current` has not changed **yet**, it is still `"categories"`, so `effect 2` will not be executed. **That's why there is no refetch.**
3. `effect 1` is executed. Now `selectedResultType === "submissions"` and `selectedResultTypeRef.current === "submissions"`.
4. Click on `users` button -> rerender.
5. Checking the dependencies: `effect 1` will be called. `selectedResultTypeRef.current` has changed from `"categories"` to `"submissions"` so `effect 2` will also be executed.
6. `effect 1` is executed. Now `selectedResultType === "users"` and `selectedResultTypeRef.current === "users"`.
7. `effect 2` is executed -> **refetch** -> `setResults` -> rerender.
8. Checking the dependencies: `effect 1` will not be called. But `effect 2` will be called because `selectedResultTypeRef.current` has changed from `"submissions"` to `"users"`.
9. `effect 2` is executed -> **refetch** -> `setResults` -> rerender.
10. Checking the dependencies: no changes.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-refetch-65xjws?file=/src/App.js)

So it is understandable what is going on, but hard to follow.

The conclusion is very simple — **trust the linter**. It will save you a headache.

> Mutable values like 'selectedResultTypeRef.current' aren't valid
> dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.

Comment: Wow, amazing. I completely missed the effect that the `setResults` re-render has on the first effect hook. So it overrides the first effect hook because the value of `selectedResultType` hasn't changed yet, which means the second hook isn't called until later, which then ends up stacking twice with the re-render from `setResults`. Thank you so much for unraveling the chronology of the renders. Your code sample really helps visualize the component life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

For me your problem is all about when React checks the dependency array of an `useEffect`, to know if this `selectedResultTypeRef.current = selectedResultType` in the first `useEffect` will tell the second one which has `selectedResultTypeRef.current` as dependency to call its callback.

I searched, one article led me to another until I found [A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by by Dan Abramov. After reading it, I understood that on a render phase, React doesn't know what happens in the callback, it just check the dependency array. A quote talking about an `useEffect` that has `name` as dependency:

> It’s like if we told React: “Hey, I know you can’t see inside this function, but I promise it only uses `name` and nothing else from the render scope.”

Knowing that, when you change `selectedResultType`, React will trigger a re-render. And while re-rendering, it would read top to bottom the component, sees your tow below  useEffect:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
  console.log('selectedResultType', selectedResultType);
  selectedResultTypeRef.current = selectedResultType
}, [selectedResultType])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('selectedResultTypeRef.current', selectedResultTypeRef.current);
  fetchResults()
}, [selectedResultTypeRef.current])
```

For the first one React sees `selectedResultType` in the dependency array and it has changed (the reason we are in this render phase), so React notes that it will run the callback after the DOM is updated.

Then React sees the second one with `selectedResultTypeRef.current` as dependency, and because the callback of the first one did not run yet, `selectedResultTypeRef.current` is the same as the previous one, so it ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think i have the answer to your problem. But I can shine a light.

a react useRef is a mutable container, this means that it should not be used as a dependency in a useEffect. I believe this would be where the issue lies, it is not a reliable dependency and should never be used like that, this is not the expected use case within reactjs.

for a better explanation, please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476525/4224964