# React useRef current not updating every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that uses the `useRef` hook on a div in order to calculate the height whenever a component is removed from that div.

The problem I am having is that the `clientHeight` is not always updating when I remove an element from the div. It does work if I use `useState` and a `useEffect`. Is there any reason why the following method won't work? How can I get this to work without using more state and another useEffect?

Doesnt work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setAppNotificationHeight(notificationRef.current?.clientHeight));
  }, [notificationRef.current?.clientHeight]);
```

Works:

```
  const [height, setHeight] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(notificationRef.current?.clientHeight);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setAppNotificationHeight(height));
  }, [height]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476155/is-it-safe-to-use-ref-current-as-useeffects-dependency-when-ref-points-to-a-dom). Mutating a reference does not necessarily trigger a rerender, and does not necessarily trigger the useEffect. You could use a useCallback hook instead of your working solution (see code snippet from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67906087/20025573) answer in particular).