# How can I properly determine when a conditionally rendered child component's forwardRef is initialized?

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref, forward-reference

I am working with a component which is wrapped with a `ContainerLoading` component which will conditionally render `children` with a `forwardRef` attached to one of the child components (`TestChild`) once loading is complete.  When wrapped with this component, the passed ref will initially render on page load as `undefined` (as it hasn't been rendered yet) and will continue to remain `undefined` until the child is rendered.

**ContainerLoading.jsx**

```
const ContainerLoading = ({ children, loading, loadingMessage }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {loading && <>{loadingMessage && <p>{loadingMessage}</p>}</>}
      {!loading && children}
    </>
  );
};
```

**App.jsx**

```
export default function App() {
  const testRef = useRef();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Your div object", testRef.current);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
  });

  return (
    <ContainerLoading loading={loading} loadingMessage={"Loading"}>
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Nested Ref Demo</h1>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flexWrap: "wrap"
        }}
      >
        <TestChild ref={testRef} />
      </div>
    </ContainerLoading>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit friendly-glitter-uq3r2o]

I've discovered that I can utilize a `useEffect` with `testRef.current` as a dependency to determine when the ref is initialized, though I've read that this is an anti-pattern (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476525/596505) and we should be utilizing a `useCallback` pattern to set the ref, as shown below:

```
const handleSetRef = useCallback((node) => {
  setRef(node);
}, []);

// Code removed for brevity

<TestChild ref={handleSetRef} />
```

Unfortunately this pattern doesn't seem to work due to the `ContainerLoading` component in combination with the `TestChild` component also utilizing a `forwardRef`.  The only way I can think to get this working properly is to utilize the aforementioned anti-pattern.

Note that when changing `TestChild` to a `div`, everything works properly.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish what I need, preferably without modifying the either the `TestChild` or `ContainerLoading` components?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand whats not working or what expected from your sandbox example

Comment: @DennisVash, essentially if I change `TestChild` to a `div`, the `handleRef` callback gets called automatically on page load.  If I leave it as `TestChild`, that `handleRef` doesn't get called until there's a re-render.  I'm trying to figure out why when the element is a child component it doesn't work, but when it's simply a `div` it does.  Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: Just pass the forwardedRef to the inner div, whatever you trying to do with setRefs should be handled by dedicated hook "useImperativeHandle" https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useImperativeHandle