# Why does my console.log run just once? I expect running after each one second

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I expect my console.log to show the current value of `prevValueRef` each one second. I checked and I saw that `prevValueRef` is increasing each second but it doesn't show it in the console each second while I console it after setting the new value to my ref. It just shows it in first console.log:

```
const PreviousValueComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const prevValueRef = useRef();
  const changeRef = useRef(value); //value is a constant number like 4 for example.

  useEffect(() => {
    prevValueRef.current = changeRef.current;
    console.log(`prevValueRef is: ${prevValueRef.current}`)
  }, [changeRef.current]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        changeRef.current++;
    }, 1000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current Value: {value}</p>
      <p>Previous Value: {prevValueRef.current}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I expected this in the console:

```
prevValueRef is:4
prevValueRef is:5
prevValueRef is:6
.
.
.
```

But it just shows the first one and when I force my component to a rerender after a while, it shows the updated value that is increased:

```
prevValueRef is:4
prevValueRef is:682
```

**Edit:** I expected my first useEffect to run after any change to it's dependecy(here for ever) without any re-rendering. Was I doing the wrong way?

Comment: As far as i am concerned useRef does not cause re-renders. As explained in the caveats seen here: https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef

Comment: Please read this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476525/9105207

In short, you rather use `useState` than `useRef` for this scenario

Comment: @TalRofe But I don't want any re-render to my component. I expect my first useEffect to run after every change to it's dependency that is `changeRef.current` without any re-render.

Comment: Why don't you want it to re-render? Of course you need it to, if you want to see visual change of your component (as it seen from you question - you want) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue at hand is that useRef is just a plain javascript object. When you modify the ref.current React has no way of knowing that the value has changed and therefore does not re-render(https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef). If you want react to re-render on update of value you'd be better off using the useState-hook along the lines of this:

```
const [previousValue, setPreviousValue] = useState();
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(value);
```

You'd then alter these values by calling their respective setter, e.g.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setPreviousValue(currentValue);
    console.log(`previousValue is: ${previousValue}`)
  }, [currentValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setCurrentValue(currentValue++);
    }, 1000)
  }, [])
```

EDIT::
Adding solution as discussed in comments. Where one of the useEffect-calls are replaced by a function which the setInterval-function calls:

```
  const updatePrevValueRef = (value) => {
    prevValueRef.current = value;
    console.log(`prevValueRef is: ${prevValueRef.current}`)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        changeRef.current++;
        updatePrevValueRef(changeRef.current);
    }, 1000)
  }, [])
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. But if you check my comment, I  was trying to see the bahaviour of useRef that I know it doesn't re-render the component and I was trying to change my ref(prevValueRef) without any re-rendering. And I knew I shouldn't change my first useEffect's dependency with something like setState, because I didn't want my component to re-render so I decided to use another useRef(changeRef) to change that dependency and then having console.log after every change.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi if i am not mistaken useEffect is only called on re-render. Not allowing re-render is essentially saying that post first-render you're never going to call useEffect again. Your other choice would be to create a separate function that is called from the function defined inside the setInterval.

Answer (score -1):

I have done some changes in your code, you can try this :

```
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(value);
  const [previousValue, setPreviousValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setPreviousValue(currentValue);
      setCurrentValue((prevValue) => prevValue + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [currentValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Previous Value: ${previousValue}`);
  }, [previousValue]);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, I needed it with using ref and not re-rendering my component:) I tried it and it works, though.

Comment: How is this different than what is suggested in the other answer, other than not providing any sort of explanation?