Difference Between useMemo and useEffect With Ref Dependencies
In React, both useEffect and useMemo have a dependencies argument.
I naively thought they worked identically: whenever the values in that dependencies argument changed, I thought the useEffect or useMemo callback would be run, and that the  only difference was just timing (useMemo runs before the render, while useEffect runs after).
In general, they are identical.  But when I have a ref as a dependency, they aren't:
const Foo = ()=> {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => console.log('effect ref', ref), [ref]);
  useMemo(() => console.log('memo ref', ref), [ref]);
  return <div ref={ref}>Foo</div>
}

Sandbox Link (Click the console icon in the upper-right to see the logs)
As I understand it Foo should render twice.  The first time through, ref.current will be undefined, and the second time it will be set to the <div>.  Thus, I'd expect that to see two useEffect logs of effect ref div, because the ref will be set both after render #1 and render #2.  And I do ...

effect ref {current: div}


effect ref {current: div}

However, with the memo logs I never see the div logged. Instead, I just see the same thing repeated:

memo ref undefined


memo ref undefined

That's expected for the first call, since the component hasn't rendered yet ... but before the second render, after the first, shouldn't the ref be set to the <div>, and so shouldn't useMemo log it?  Instead, it seems useMemo is never run.
In short, while I mostly understand how useMemo works, it seems I'm missing some key detail that explains why it will never log a ref's value, and I'd appreciate any help explaining why.
P.S. I realize I could probably solve all this by making useRef depend on a state variable, and then making a useEffect which updates that state variable when the ref changes ... but I'm more focused on trying to understand the problem first before I solve it.

A ref is a stable object reference though, so even if the current value inside changes, the outer ref is still the same. So I wouldn't expect either the memo or effect to run twice. The sandbox link doesn't seem to be working, but is it possible that StrictMode is interfering by running these twice on the same render?

But whether ref is a stable object or not, I'm doing two renders, right?  On render #1 the ref.current is undefined, and on render #2 (and 3, and ...) ref.current has been set.  If I understand that correctly, then if I see two logs from useMemo callbacks, that must mean useMemo ran once before the first render, and once before the second.  Shouldn't that second one have logged the ref, since it should have been set by then?  I know I'm misunderstanding something in there, but I'm not sure what.

What I'm suggesting is that it's not doing two renders, or that it's doing two renders only due to React.StrictMode which may behave differently than a normal re-render.

My reasoning is that your effect and memo are basically configured to only ever run once, and yet you're seeing them run twice. The only explanation I've seen for that in the React world is Strict Mode. And it's hard to understand the normal cycle of things with strict mode in play so I wanted to bring it up to rule out first

Oh, I think I understand now.   If I grok you, you're saying the logs I'm seeing reflect multiple pre-DOM (ie. pre-able-to-set-the-ref) renders?  I thought a component only ever rendered once without a ref, and the ref was always set by render #2 ... but you're suggesting that I'm seeing logs from multiple renders from before the ref is set (because "React Strict Mode" causes a second pre-ref-setting render)?

Frankly its hard to keep up with all the oddities StrictMode can cause, but as we're discussing this I believe they added a new on in React 18 that causes components to double mount - which could definitely explain this behavior. Let me see if I can find a link to the docs on that behavior

If you could throw that link into an answer, it certainly seems like the best explanation anyone has presented, so I'll happily upvote it (and accept it after the 24 hour window if nothing else comes up).

Annoyingly, I could not find this info in the documentation, only in the React 18 release announcement - https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18#new-strict-mode-behaviors - "This new check will automatically unmount and remount every component, whenever a component mounts for the first time, restoring the previous state on the second mount"

There is sort of a mention of it in the docs here - https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-re-running-effects-in-development - "When Strict Mode is on, React will also run one extra setup+cleanup cycle in development for every Effect. This may feel surprising, but it helps reveal subtle bugs that are hard to catch manually."

This behavior is due to React.StrictMode, not from using a ref as a dependency.
A ref is a stable object reference across renders, and useEffect and useMemo use a referential equality check to determine if their dependencies have changed. Therefore, under normal circumstances (a prod build for example) these hooks would only run one time.
Since you are seeing evidence that they are running more than once, the answer is Strict Mode.
The explanation for this comes from a few different sections of the documentation.
https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode

Your components will re-run Effects an extra time to find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup

https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#caveats

In Strict Mode, React will call your calculation function twice in order to help you find accidental impurities. This is development-only behavior and does not affect production. If your calculation function is pure (as it should be), this should not affect your logic. The result from one of the calls will be ignored.

https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18#new-strict-mode-behaviors
It's also possible (but impossible to tell) that it could be caused by React 18 StrictMode re-mounting every component.

Use effect would trigger an action based off the changed ref where has memo will be a variable, and you will need to return something.
For example:

const Foo = ()=> {
  const user = authHook(); // whatever here

  useEffect(() => console.log('user full name', `${user.firstname} ${user.lastname}` ), [user]); // will trigger when the user changes and outputs to console the user fill name

  const fullname = useMemo(() => `${user.firstname} ${user.lastname}`, [user]); // returns a variable that can be used in your code and will auto update when the user changes but wont reivaluate when anything else changes

  return <div>{fullname}</div>
}


I think whats happening in your question in particular is that you are passing the ref when you should be passing ref.current

Thanks, but again I'm not looking for a solution, I'm looking for an explanation of how useMemo works, in particular how it handles ref dependencies differently from useEffect.

this might answer your question then, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67906087/10037470 seems that there are issues with useMemo and useEffect with refs, so using useCallback is the suggested method.

That link is interesting, but it still doesn't answer my question. That link is saying that when you use useEffect with a ref dependency, ref changes don't trigger a re-render/useEffect callback.  That's correct, but my question isn't about triggering callbacks: as you can see from sandbox, the callbacks are being triggered.  My question is about what they log when they are triggered: it seems like the second useMemo callback/log message should occur after the ref has been set, so I don't understand why it's not logging the ref.
